# How works this code(Display digits in English) ? step by step

Tags: c

I wrote this program (Display digits in English) with use of modular. Then I found this program with another approach to solve. I'm curious about how works this code. I've tried in my mind calculate input 101 step by step but I couldn't reach desirable result (I've tried with `number < 100` and i got it, but when `number >=100` I can't got it how it works). However code works fine. 
Help me got it step by step. 
Or maybe you can recommend me IDE for C-language for that would I can use the debugger and see with my own eyes what's happening step by step.
Thank you!

I not correctly understood this expression while ( number / power > 9 ) power *= 10; Now it's clear.

```
// Display digits in English

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int number, digit;

    printf ("Type an integer\n");
    scanf  ("%i", &number);

    int power = 1;
    while ( number / power > 9 )
        power *= 10;

    do {
        digit = number / power;
        number -= digit * power;
        power /= 10;

        switch ( digit ) {
            case 0:
                printf ("zero ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf ("one ");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf ("two ");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf ("three ");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf ("four ");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf ("five ");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf ("six ");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf ("seven ");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf ("eight ");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf ("nine ");
                break;
        }
    }
    while ( power != 0 );

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To gain understanding of how code works you should use a debugger, ans step through it

Comment: Use the concept of tens digit, hundreds digit and thousand digits for this

Comment: Using a piece of paper and a pencil.

Comment: @t.m. Because she wants the first digit first. The modulo operator gives the last digit.

Comment: @t.m. For a 5-digit number it takes 5 rounds in the first loop. What would be improved by modulo? Can't see the value of the modulo value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many IDE`s for C. You can try some of these and choose which you like:

- Microsoft Visual Studio
- Eclipse
- NetBeans
- CLion
- and much more

If you want just to debug, and you use Linux you can use GDB debugger.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic for SO.  Such questions should be closed, not answered.  Where such a question is one aspect of a larger question, that aspect should not be answered, unless by pointing out that that aspect is OT.